# Which iDevice is best for iPhone apps testing?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I am planning to buy any `iDevices` low cost `(iPhone or iPod)` for test my `iPhone application ( iOS 5 to 9)`, I am confused,which one is best for test my application.

Application Info :

1. Need Internet
2. Support all iPhone models
3. Maps
4. Music
5. Camera (back and rear)

In market we have lots of devices available `iPhone 4s, 5c, 5s, 6, 6 plus, iPad mini 2,3, iPad retina,etc,...`

I am confusing which one is most suitable for app development and testing.  Some peoples says `iPhone 4s` cheapest price with good performance but you cant update OS above 9.

Please tel me one device for development and testing if `iPod 6 generation` suitable mean I am very happy. please post your ideas.

Comment: If you use it only for development, use the 4s. It has the worst performance and forces you to think about optimisation.

Comment: Yes only for development testing But now If I buy that one we cant update iOS above 9. apple aso planning to stop that one right?@dasdom

Comment: That is correct. Most probably.

Comment: Well the 5 would have the second worst performance so you could buy that if you're worried about losing support.

Comment: This question is primarily opinion based so based on that I am voting to close however I will still give my opinion. I agree with `dasdom` in that developing on a 4s would be good because it would make you think more about it. But for me I'd probably say you need to buy a minimum of two devices, low end iPhone 4s and high end iPhone 6 then you are covering both basis because the iPhone 6 will affect very differently to the iPhone 4s and you will be covered for some time with the updates for iOS whereas the iPhone 4s is very much about to go bye bye for support of iOS.

Comment: What about iPod touch 6th generation? Its suitable for iPhone apps testing ?@dasdom and @Braains

Comment: Yes you could use an iPod 6th gen instead of iPhone 6

Comment: If I test iPhone apps via iPod touch 6th generation...its good for all device compatability? I agree Iphone 6 for higherend but for lowerend otherthan iPhone 4s...with ios 9 above updates...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends what you are after. Every single iPhone that's available for sale meets all your criteria besides being supported for iOS 9. If iOS9 is a must then I'll defer you to the list of devices that are supported: *iPhone 6 Plus*, *iPhone 6*, *iPhone 5S*, *iPhone 5C*, *iPhone 5*, *iPhone 4S*, *iPad Air 2*, *iPad Air*, *iPad 4*, *iPad 3*, *iPad 2*, *iPad Mini 3*, *iPad Mini 2*, *iPad Mini*, *iPod Touch 5G*, *iPod Touch 6G*.
 I think the real questio comes down to two things: is this going to be your daily phone, and how much are you willing to spend?

**If this is going to be your daily phone,** then the answer is simple, get the latest iPhone model you can budget. If your concern is to build apps that fit on a smaller screen or weaker hardware, then the iOS simulator that the iOS development kit comes with allows you to run the simulator on all iOS screen sizes and lets you limit the simulators performance to match that of the hardware being simulated.

**If you're going to get a phone that you're only developing on** then you'll probably want an iPhone 5 since it is the cheapest model that will support iOS 9. If it wasn't for iOS 9 I would suggest the 4s due to its small screen and limited performance (by todays standards). This will force you to make an app that is as easily scalable and compatible as possible to smaller screen space and weaker hardware. But the same can be true of the 5 models, just to a lesser extent.

**A wildcard choice is the touch 5G**, which for the most part behaves almost exactly like an iPhone 5 that can only access data through WiFi. This would probably be the best choice if for example you want the cheapest development device possible, because you use a non-iOS device as your daily cellphone. I have a co-worker that actually does this and it works really well so long as you don't need to test stuff out outside of wifi range.

**Just remember** you don't need a physical device to test iOS apps, all you need is [xCode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/), and its iOS simulator.

It is just easier and more effective to test with a physical device, but not at all necessary

Comment: What about iPod touch 6th gen?

Comment: Sorry forgot they just released that one, and yes it definitely works with iOS 9, it's just more expensive and not as good a choice if you just want a cheap development only device.

Comment: I am ready to buy iPod touch 6th gen. Its good for development tesing iPhone apps or not?

Comment: Yes, it is fully compatible for development, just keep in mind that you don't need a physical device to test apps on, you can also use the built in simulator on your development kit.

Comment: Alrigth Thank you. I will buy a ipod touch 6th gen for iPhone  app development testing only. Thank you @Mark Haus

Answer (score 0):

I think iPhone 5S (or same-hardware-iPod if any) would be good for you. It will support the next couple of iOS versions. After all you will be able to test different screen sizes on the Simulator!

Comment: Ipod touch 6th generation Ok for testing iPhone apps...Its covering all the functionality without calls?Give me one choice iPhone 5 or iPod touch 6th generation?@dizza213

Comment: This is a comment as it is your opinion and doesn't really answer the question which have to be fact based.

Comment: Sorry Popeye. I am fixed iPod touch 6th generation. I am asking its possbile to test iPhone apps without specify any iPod screen sizes?